# Add another detail band Jasperreports

Tags: jasper-reports

Hello I would like to add another detail band between the momskod group footer 1 and 2. I searched for a solution and tried a lot of things, but I can't just make it. Is there any possibility? See the image below for more details. I'm using Jaspersoft iReport Designer 4.5.1.

[image]

EDIT:

Well, the issue is that for some outputs (groups) in Detail 1 I want a summation of them below the content of momskod Group Footer 1. For example is the content of Detail 1 is the following:

Customer 1: 200

Customer 2: 200

Customer 1: 300

Then I want to output beneath momskod Group Footer 1:

Customer 1: 500

Customer 2: 200

I have written a query to support this, but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

For that problem, I would add a sub-report that queries the summations, because you cannot add a detail bar between the footers.

Answer (score 0):

You can only have 1 detail band. A detail band will be reapeated for each row your query has. If you want many reports in one page you need subreports. you can put them one bellow the other but all of them in one detail band.